# Lightning combobox not showing values

Tags: lightning-web-components, selectoption, lightning-combobox

[image]

[image]

**Below is my code I have combobox values in my activityOptions but my combobox does not displays anything. Please help me with this issue.**

*.js*

```
// Complete activity
    for (let v of this.activity) {
        this.complete_activity.push(v.option);
        this.dropDown["Complete Activity?"] = this.complete_activity;
        
       // console.log('this.complete_activity : '+this.complete_activity);
    }
    this.activityOptions = [{label : this.complete_activity, value : this.complete_activity}];
        console.log('this.activityOptions : '+JSON.stringify(this.activityOptions));
```

*.html*

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        Hello
        <lightning-combobox name="SelectOption" label="Complete Activity?" 
        options={activityOptions} 
           required>
        </lightning-combobox>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/documentation):

> In your JavaScript, define an array of options. Each option corresponds to a list item on the dropdown list. Define the content of each option by specifying a value property and a label property. The label value is displayed for the item in the rendered dropdown list, while the value property's value is stored when the item is selected.

So `activityOptions` must be an array of object with two string properties: `label` and `value`.

```
[
    { label: 'Not Started Yet', value: 'Not Started Yet' },
    { label: 'Started', value: 'Started' },
    { label: 'Complete', value: 'Complete' }
]
```

Instead, as shown by the console.log, you created and array with a single element whose `label` and `value` properties are arrays:

```
[
    {
        label: [ 'Not Started Yet', 'Started', 'Complete' ],
        value: [ 'Not Started Yet', 'Started', 'Complete' ]
    }
]
```

In order to fix it, you should modify your for-loop:

```
// Complete activity
const comboboxOptions = [];
for (const v of this.activity) {
    this.complete_activity.push(v.option);
    this.dropDown["Complete Activity?"] = this.complete_activity;
    
   // console.log('this.complete_activity : '+this.complete_activity);
   
   comboboxOptions.push({ label: v.option, value: v.option });
}
this.activityOptions = comboboxOptions;
console.log('this.activityOptions: ', this.activityOptions);
```

Please note that special characters must be escaped. I.E. if you want to display `"Hello World"` the label should be `label: '\"Hello World\"'`.

Comment: thanks buddy it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

@Indresh, please elaborate a bit more what is your expected output as it is difficult to comprehend with just this line `not displays anything`.

Also you may want to compare your code against the below LWC and see what you are missing https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/example

Comment: I have edited my question and attached the screenshot of my lightning combobox. My combobox is not displaying the option values.